# React hooks updating state, but component is not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using react hooks for a while, but i'm facing a problem to update a component, using an input type file. Here is the code:

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const fileInputRef = [];
  Array.from(Array(FILES_QUANTITY)).map(x => 
  fileInputRef.push(React.createRef()));

 return (
    <div className="buttons-div">
      {Array.from(Array(FILES_QUANTITY)).map((f, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="buttons-input">
          {console.log(index, files[index])}
          <Button
            content={files[index] ? files[index].name : 'Choose a file'}
            labelPosition="left"
            icon="file"
            onClick={() => fileInputRef[index].current.click()}
          />
          {filesName[index]}
          <input ref={fileInputRef[index]} type="file" hidden onChange={e => fileChange(e, index)} accept=".pdf" />
        </div>
      ))}
      <ButtonActions />
    </div>
  );
```

So basically, when I change the file in the input, I would expect to the content of the button change with the name of the file. Although the console shows the correct name, the button component don't get updated.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just answering my own question, the problem was when I was trying to update the state.
This was the problem:
```Javascript
// Wrong
const updateFiles = files;
// Right
const updateFiles = [...files];
            updateFiles[buttonIndex] = { name: file.name, result: event.target.result };
            setFiles(updateFiles);
```

Comment: if you have a solution, write that as an answer to your own question, so we can close this. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering my own question, the problem was when I was trying to update the state. This was the problem: Javascript // Wrong const updateFiles = files; // Right const updateFiles = [...files]; updateFiles[buttonIndex] = { name: file.name, result: event.target.result }; setFiles(updateFiles);